# Windsor: How can I specify Inspectionbehaviour.None so than Castle won't autoresolve properties fluently?

Tags: castle-windsor

I see that i can specify this behavior in xml by using the following:

```
<component
  id="notification"
  service="Acme.Crm.Services.INotificationService, Acme.Crm"
  type="Acme.Crm.Services.EmailNotificationService, Acme.Crm"
  inspectionBehavior="none">
</component>
```

But how do I do this using fluent registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (but I didn't like it)

```
        container.Register(Component.For<SomeClassWithPropertyWhichWindsorWillAutoInject>()
            .Configuration(Attrib.ForName("inspectionBehavior").Eq("none"))
```